# How to change default Umask of MyQL 8.0

Tags: unix, umask

I'm using mysql 8.0.34.

When I executed the sql 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE',

the access privileges are0640 files are created.

I want to change file permission of created by the sql to 0666,
so I create /etc/sysconfig/mysql file,
and write it environmental variables,

```
UMASK=0666
```

I started mysql again with

```
systemctl start mysqld
```

, but the file was created at 0640 as well by the sql.

How to create the 0666 permision file with
'SELECT INTO OUTFILE' of mysql?
What should I do?

Comment: [unix.stackexchange.com: How to set default file permissions for all folders/files in a directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory)